# Firestore array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I try to convert firestore document array to normal array to reuse it in drop down list. my code

```
let db = firebase.firestore();
var user = db.collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email);

user.get()
.then(function (doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {

    //var myArray = doc.data().user_categories.split(",");
    swal(doc.data().user_categories);
  } else {
    swal("Error!", "No such document!", "error");
  }
}).catch(function (error) {
  swal("Error!", error, "error");
});
```

[image]

the split doesn't work and the alert shows:
"1st argument ('BS,Demar,Dino,HKL,HKM,Muflon') is invalid"

"

Comment: please add your `swal` function implementation

Comment: Sorry swal is sweetallert plugin. It can be alert only and it is not important in yhis case.I neet transfer doc.data().user_categories(which is firestore array) to normal array. Unfortunatelly var myArray = doc.data().user_categories.split(",") doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I searched on internet for the same question, but later I found a great alternative to Firebase Array.

Instead of Firebase Array, use Firebase maps in firestore that will help you to work similarly with Vanilla JavaScript Array.

[Visit Official Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map)

Comment: there are cases in which you need arrays, for instance when the number of elements at of elements is not known at the beginning. The question was specific, your answer was not helpful. Downvoted @anshu-meena